# vuechartJs make a label dynamic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to do a pie chart with vue chart, I am trying to convert an object into an array to update de label in vuechartjs and make it dynamic according to the api, but it seems almost impossible. My goal is to fetch the concert name in the label and then fetch (data) how many booking we have for each concert. Would someone would be kind enough to  help ? I have tried everything. thanks Here is my code :

```
  <script>
 import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
extends: Pie,
data () {
  return {
    bandNames:[],
    booking:[],
    bandName:[],
    data:[],
    chartData: {
      labels:[],

      datasets: [{
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'            
          ],
          backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',                
          ],
          data: [1000]
        }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  }
},
created(){
     var vm = this;
  this.axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/booking', {})

    .then(function (response) {
    
      console.log(response.data);
      vm.booking = response.data;
    });

    this.axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/concerts', {})

    .then(function (response) {
     
      console.log(response.data);
      vm.bandNames = response.data;

      vm.bandNames.forEach((item)=>{
        vm.bandName.push(item.band)
      })

      vm.chartData.labels = vm.bandName[0]
      var data = []
      var i = vm.bandName.length
     for(var a = 0 ; a < i ; a++){
       data.push([vm.bandName[a]])
       vm.chartData.labels = data

     }
      
      
    });
},
mounted () {
  this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please reformat your code ? And provide a minimum reproducible example with a result you're facing?

Comment: Here it is I formatted the code and added more info on what I am trying to achieve thank you

Comment: Great! My first guess would be testing the URL you provided http://localhost:3000/concerts if it gives you the JSON array you want in the format you need. If so, you could add here the format of the JSON data, e.g. [{name: "Band1", attendance: 1000}, ....].

Comment: Besides, I think you should place this vm.chartData.labels = data outside of the for loop.

Comment: Basically I am using mongoDB, so the url is returning me an array of object. This is what I am trying to understand. Is there a way to convert this array of  object in a simple array ? thank you for your reply

Comment: I don't know any specific way for converting mongoDB objects into simple array, you have to iterate over it as you're doing in vm.bandNames.forEach((item)=>{         vm.bandName.push(item.band)  }). But since you want to convert to a simple array, not array of objects, I suppose you must first create an empty array and then push the items into this local empty array. At the end you can push the filled array to the bandName array, therefore resulting in a 2-d array. Is that what you want?

Comment: please provide some return values of your api

Answer (score 0):

You can directly push the labels to the chartOptions in the loop , so change this :

```
vm.bandNames.forEach((item)=>{
  vm.bandName.push(item.band)
 })
vm.chartData.labels = vm.bandName[0]
```

by :

```
    vm.bandNames.forEach((item)=>{
           vm.chartData.labels.push(item.band)
   })
```